# Let $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $A_f=c(f) $ be the companion matrix of $f$. Given $ g \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ show that $ \dim \ker g(A_f) \leq \deg g $.

Tags: linear-algebra, companion-matrices

**Theorem**: Let $ f \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ and $ A_f = c(f) $ be the companion matrix of $ f $.
Given $ g \in \mathbb{F}[x] $ show that $ \dim \ker g(A_f) \leq \deg g $. ( Hint: show that  $ \deg f - \deg g $ first columns of $ g(A_f) $ are linearly independent. )

I have no Idea what to do. I wrote
$ g(x) = b_0 + b_1 \cdot x+...+ b_{m-1} \cdot x^{m-1} + b_m \cdot x^m $,
$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 \cdot x +...+ a_{n-1} \cdot x^{n-1} + a_n \cdot x^n $.
$c(f)=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -a_{0} \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -a_{1} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -a_{2} \\ & \vdots & & & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -a_{n-1}\end{array}\right)$  .
$ g(A_f) = b_0 I_n + b_1 A_f + ... + b_{m-1} A_f^{m-1} + b_m A_f^m $.
I got stuck because I have no idea how the matrix $ g(A_f) $ should look like in general, so I couldn't proceed to find $ \dim \ker g(A_f) $.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you try to calculate the power of the matrix $A_f$, you will get it at once. First, let's do it for $A_f^2$, its first n-2 columns are exactly the 2~ n-1 columns of $A_f$ :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & & & &*&*\\
0 &0& & &*&*\\
1 &0&0&& *&*\\
\vdots&\vdots& \vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&* &*
\end{pmatrix}$$
it is obvious that the first $n-2$ columns are linearly independent, and we can ignore how the last two columns looks like exactly. Similarly, for $A_f^3$, its first $n-3$ columns are the 3~n-1 columns of $A_f$, and so on.

Then, the matrix $g(A_f)$ looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix}
b_0& & & &*&*\\
b_1&\ddots& & &*&*\\
b_2 &\ddots&b_0&& *&*\\
\vdots&\ddots&b_1&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
b_m&\vdots &b_2 & \cdots& *&*\\
\vdots&\ddots &\vdots& &\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&b_m&\cdots&* &*
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since $b_m\neq 0$, we derive what we want.

Comment: Very good, I actually calculated the example: $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 0 & 0 & -a_{0} \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -a_{1} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -a_{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -a_{3}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 0 & 0 & -a_{0} \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -a_{1} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -a_{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -a_{3}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 0 & -a_{0} & a_{0} a_{3} \\ 0 & 0 & -a_{1} & a_{1} a_{3}-a_{0} \\ 1 & 0 & -a_{2} & a_{2} a_{3}-a_{1} \\ 0 & 1 & -a_{3} & a_{3}^{2}-a_{2}\end{array}\right)$ But didn't notice that these two linearly independent columns would lead me anywhere.